# Compare two List<List<String>> in java and find the incorrect data and missing rows

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, set

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<List<String>> preCSV = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> postCSV = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add data to preCSV
        List<String> preList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        preList1.add("apple");
        preList1.add("banana");
        preList1.add("cherries");
        preCSV.add(preList1);

        List<String> preList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        preList2.add("orange");
        preList2.add("pear");
        preList2.add("grape");
        preCSV.add(preList2);

        List<String> preList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        preList3.add("watermelon");
        preList3.add("kiwi");
        preList3.add("pineapple");
        preCSV.add(preList3);

       // Add data to postCSV
        List<String> postList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        postList1.add("apple");
        postList1.add("banana");
        postList1.add("cherry");
        postCSV.add(postList1);

        List<String> postList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        postList2.add("orange");
        postList2.add("pear");
        postList2.add("grape");
        postCSV.add(postList2);

        List<List<String>> missingLists = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> mismatchedData= new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < preCSV.size(); i++) {
            List<String> preList = preCSV.get(i);
            boolean rowFound = false;
            for (List<String> postList : postCSV) {
                if (preList.size() == postList.size() && preList.equals(postList)) {
                    rowFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!rowFound) {
                boolean allMismatch = true; // assume all indices mismatch
                for (int j = 0; j < postCSV.size(); j++) {
                    List<String> postList = postCSV.get(j);
                    int mismatch = 0;
                    if (preList.size() == postList.size()) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < preList.size(); k++) {
                            if (!preList.get(k).equals(postList.get(k))) {
                                mismatch++;
                                break; // break as soon as a mismatch is found
                            }
                        }
                        if (mismatch == 0) { // if all indices match, set allMismatch to false
                            allMismatch = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (allMismatch) { // add preList to missingLists if all indices mismatch
                    missingLists.add(preList);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(missingLists.size()); // Output: 1
        System.out.println(missingLists.get(0)+" "+ missingLists.get(1)); // Output should only contain [watermelon, kiwi, pineapple]


    }
```

The above code consider prelist1 as a missing list but it should not be considered as missinglist it should be a mismatched data

**Actual Output:** missing contains [apple, banana, cherries] [watermelon, kiwi, pineapple]
**Expected Output:**
missingLists = [watermelon, kiwi, pineapple]  and
mismatchedData = [apple, banana, cherries]

Comment: as commented in code `// if all indices match, set allMismatch to false` - `"cherry"` does not match `"cherries"` -> not all indices match -> allMismatch is not set to false (BTW no CSV, no file related question)

Comment: @user16320675 thanks for your quick reply ! , yes in the above list only cherry is not matching with cherries where as the other two (apple and banana ) are matching so it shouldnt be considered as a missing list, it is a mismatchedata

Comment: Precisely define "missing list" and "mistmatch data" first, please. With the help of "some match", "all match", "no match" or alike at least.

Comment: @user16320675 if all the elements of prelist is not matched then it should be considered as missing list other wise it's a mistmatch. For example instead of cherries if it is a mango then also it should be considered as a mismatch not a missinglist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else can resolve it by using stream to simplify your code, but anyway it works now and hopefully, it helps you to resolve the problem! Good luck

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;


public class CSVFileComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> preCSV = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> postCSV = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add data to preCSV
        List<String> preList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        preList1.add("apple");
        preList1.add("cherries");
        preList1.add("banana");
        preCSV.add(preList1);

        List<String> preList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        preList2.add("orange");
        preList2.add("pear");
        preList2.add("grape");
        preCSV.add(preList2);

        List<String> preList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        preList3.add("watermelon");
        preList3.add("kiwi");
        preList3.add("pineapple");
        preCSV.add(preList3);

        // Add data to postCSV
        List<String> postList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        postList1.add("apple");
        postList1.add("banana");
        postList1.add("cherry");
        postCSV.add(postList1);

        List<String> postList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        postList2.add("orange");
        postList2.add("pear");
        postList2.add("grape");
        postCSV.add(postList2);

        List<List<String>> missingLists = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> mismatchedData= new ArrayList<>();

        Consumer<List<String>> searchList = element -> {
            boolean isfound = false;
            boolean isEqual = false;
            for (List<String> list : postCSV) {
                List<String> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);
                listCopy.retainAll(element);
                if (listCopy.size() > 0 && listCopy.size() != list.size()) {
                    isfound = true;
                } else if (listCopy.size() == element.size()) {
                    isEqual = true;
                }
            }
            if (isfound)
                mismatchedData.add(element);
            else if (!isEqual)
                missingLists.add(element);
        };

        preCSV.stream().forEach(searchList);



        System.out.println(missingLists); // Output: 1
        System.out.println(mismatchedData); // Output: 1

    }

}
```